# Can I use AgensGraph on Cloud environment?

Tags: cloud, agens-graph

I'm using the AgensGraph on my server(On-premise). 
If I want AgensGraph to put in Cloud environment, can I? 
I couldn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AgensGraph Community version is available on AWS marketplace, for more imfomation please visit the following link:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07NYTX2YH

You can also easily have AgensGraph on Microsoft Azure and Google Cloud as well with using the same usage instruction of AgensGraph on AWS Marketplace.